# Tensorflow sequence to sequence models

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting the following errors when I try to execute "translate.py" in the sequence to sequence models tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/). Can anyone please help me.

Errors:

```
Preparing WMT data in /tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate.py", line 302, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "translate.py", line 299, in main
    train()
  File "translate.py", line 152, in train
    from_train, to_train, from_dev, to_dev, _, _ = data_utils.prepare_wmt_data(
AttributeError

: 'module' object has no attribute 'prepare_wmt_data'
```

Comment: That's a bit thin. I assume the code is too big, but can you at least provide some links to the code or tutorial?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/

Comment: I found the python files from internet. they are not present in the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the code you are using simply misses the `prepare_wmt_data` function in `data_utils.py`; it's there in [this version](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/efa4a6cfaa9d69a74fba73546ee320cf740bbc25/tutorials/rnn/translate/data_utils.py#L247) of the example. You can also have a look at the complete (and latest) version of the sequence-to-sequence example code at

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/translate

They should work with TensorFlow ~0.12.